# A 'nicer' way to display exceptions?

Tags: android, error-handling

I'm currently playing with the In-app billing process in Android, and there are countless exceptions and problems that can occur during the purchase process. It looks as if I don't fully understand the concept of dealing with program errors, as my app just displays "[App] has to be closed."

In LogCat, however, I see the exception message as defined in the code:

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Billing is not set up. Can't perform operation: " + operation);
```

Why isn't this error displayed to the user that way?

Comment: Do you handle the exceptions? Is your code wrapped in try catch blocks?

Comment: capture those exceptions and show in toast or any AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If exceptions are to be expected in some scenarios then you should really be writing defensive code by implementing try catch (and sometimes finally) blocks. Take a look at this resource - [Java Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/putItTogether.html)

Specify the error you're expecting and handle it accordingly. I would expect the application to return with a 'Toast' popup or a redirect to billing setup.

NOTE: It is very bad practise to just catch all exceptions without care for why the exception is thrown, try to be specific in the exception catching. Sometimes I'd prefer my app to crash rather than take payment and not deliver the goods.

```
try {

    // your billing code

} catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    //Handle exception - Would probably want to match the contents of e to your message 
    defined to ensure it is the correct exception (In case you've defined many of the same type)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give your users, great and clean error-messages you should try out crouton. This lets you make beautyfull messages: Take a look on the Project Website of them:
[Crouton Homepage](http://johnkil.github.com/Android-AppMsg/)

---

Back to your problem, the point is that you're doing a error-message which you can only find in the Logcatlog. If you want to show it to a user try a Toast Message or an Alertmessage. Whatever I would take a look @Crouton!

Best Regards

safari

Comment: Yes, or even a dialog to make sure that they don't miss the message that says their in app purchase has failed